# why my android app retrofit cannot connect to my backend app laravel

Tags: android, laravel, retrofit

I'm trying to post information from android to laravel by retrofit2, but it doesn't work.

The error is : HTTP FAILED: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.137.26 (port 8000) from /192.168.137.57 (port 49898) after 10000ms.

this is my APIClient Code: public class APIClient {

```
        private static Retrofit getRetrofit(){
    HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new 
    OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor).build();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl("http://192.168.1.49:8000/")
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build();
    return retrofit;
}

public static UserService getUserService(){
    UserService userService = getRetrofit().create(UserService.class);
    return userService;
}
```

this is my interface UserService Code:

```
public interface UserService { 
@POST("api/addTypeetat/") 
Call<UserRequest> saveUser(@Body UserRequest userRequest); 
}
```

my ip address is : 192.168.1.49

Comment: Did you try to open your site on the broswer? Because you are using a local server, so you must sure that your site is running well.

Comment: yes my site is working on the http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Comment: Check your server status and server firewall and make sure that the port is forwarded to your pc (if you are using local host)

Comment: @AmirHossein the server is ON and he works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by running my backend laravel on the same ip adress like android